# animation function in matplotlib is blocked when working with global variables (Animation Classes)

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

So, I have problem. I need to animate a CALP (Cascade Adaptive Linear Predictor) error. I'm using liber matplotlib (Animation Classes) for solve my task, but when I'm trying calculate new coefficient CALP, my program lock in moment `aa = aa - lmd1 * dEda(y, previus_data_1, previus_data_2)`, aa is global variable. But, if I try calculate `aa = lmd1 * dEda(y, previus_data_1, previus_data_2)`  my program work good. Lower I presented my code. Thanks in advance.

```
# Filter coefficients
aa = 0.01
bb = 0.01

# Learning rate
lmd1 = 0.0000001
lmd2 = 0.0000001

# ЛWorksheets for storing graph values
xdata, ydata = [], []
```

```
def E(y, a, b):
    return (y - a*aa - bb)**2

def dEda(y, a, b):
    return (2 * (y - a*aa - b*bb) * a)
 
def dEdb(y,  a, b):
    return (2 * (y - a*aa - bb) * 1)
```

```
%matplotlib inline
# Бесконечный цикл генерации значений (генератор потому что используется yield)
def data_gen():
    for cnt in itertools.count():
#         aa = aa - lmd1 * dEda(data[cnt+1], previus_data_1, previus_data_2)
#         bb = bb - lmd2 * dEdb(data[cnt+1], previus_data_1, previus_data_2)
#         previus_data_2 = copy.deepcopy(previus_data_1)
#         previus_data_1 = copy.deepcopy(data[cnt+1])
#         err = E(data[cnt+1], previus_data_1, previus_data_2)
        yield cnt, data[cnt+1]

# Инициализация визуализации
def init():
    #Задаем минимальные и максимлаьные значения по осям х и у
    ax.set_ylim(30000, -30000)
    ax.set_xlim(0,100)
    
    #Очищаем все данные в слистах если они присутствуют 
    del xdata[:]
    del ydata[:]
    
    #Задаем начальное значение построения графика
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line,

# Функция выполнения (передаем данные и разбиваем их) 
def run(data):
    # update the data
    t, y = data
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
#     aa = aa - lmd1 * dEda(y, previus_data_1, previus_data_2)
#     bb = bb - lmd2 * dEdb(y, previus_data_1, previus_data_2)
#     previus_data_2 = copy.deepcopy(previus_data_1)
#     previus_data_1 = copy.deepcopy(y)
    err = E(y, previus_data_1, previus_data_2)
    
    
    xdata.append(t)
    ydata.append(err)
    
    
    # Проверяем, если данные больше чем заданное значение, 
    # то изменяем размер рисунка 
    if t >= xmax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, 2*xmax)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    # задаем значения новые и возвращаем
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    return line,
```

```
%matplotlib notebook
previus_data_1 = 0
previus_data_2 = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (9, 6))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
ax.grid()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, init_func=init)
```

..........................

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved. I made mistake and forgot designate a variables as global. But now, I merely send vector weights and vector delay signal to function.

---

Thanks to all!!